# Identifying and highlighting specific coding strings from a sequence

Tags: r

Is there an easy way of highlighting or marking specific codes from a column of data?

For example in the list below for any codes containing "-R" I would like to highlight this cell along with the the cell which contains the same "UK14.013##" not containing the "-R"

```
AP-12345  
AP-54321  
AP-89521  
AP-00012  
UK14.01303-RUSG2645942  
UK14.01303USG2634960  
UK14.01304-RUSG2645942  
UK14.01304USG2634960  
UK14.01317USG2636618
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'highlight'?

Comment: The tag [r] here refers to the R programming language. Did you mean to use that tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
lines <- readLines(n=9)
AP-12345
AP-54321
AP-89521
AP-00012
UK14.01303-RUSG2645942
UK14.01303USG2634960
UK14.01304-RUSG2645942
UK14.01304USG2634960
UK14.01317USG2636618 

grep("UK14.013\\d{2}[^-R]", lines, value=TRUE)
#[1] "UK14.01303USG2634960"  "UK14.01304USG2634960"  "UK14.01317USG2636618 "

grep("-R", lines, value=TRUE)
#[1] "UK14.01303-RUSG2645942" "UK14.01304-RUSG2645942"
```

If you want just the index

```
  grep("-R", lines)
  #[1] 5 7

 grep("UK14.013\\d{2}[^-R]", lines)
 #[1] 6 8 9
```

Comment: I should have specified more clearly yesterday and apologies I may have added an incorrect tag due to inexperience on this website.  I basically just wanted to seek a way of identifying the codes in the column of data which included a "-R" and for these ones which did to also identify the same "UK14.00###" code which didnt include the "-R".  The reason for my help request is to be able to extract these identified codes from the main column of data without having to manually carry out this excercise.

Comment: @ghodgs.  Wouldn't the `grep` gives you the index to extract those elements from the column of data.  If not, please also show your expected result.  I assume that the data you showed will be from a column in your dataframe.